# Acls : memory leak caused by createAcl and updateAcl

Tags: symfony, memory-leaks

In my project, say a user1 has 8.000 articles (it's limitless actually), and he wants to show them to some users of his choice who can't normally see them, so I need to copy the acl read on the eight thousand articles. Which doesn't work because it hits the `Allowed memory size` (1GB).

So after some debugging to understand why I'm hitting 1GO-memory size, I figured out that the problèm was caused by `createdAcl` and `updateAcl`

Is it possible to free memory used by `createAcl` and `updateAcl` after they're done?

> **Update1**

This seems to be a symfony2 bug https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2376

But none of the suggested workarounds worked for me :/

Comment: It's probably better to do these updates in batches of 100

Comment: How do I do it? given that the memory is freed after the apache instance is done. Are u talking about maybe asynchronous tasks?